# Communication between USB peripheral devices

Tags: usb

Are two USB devices, connected to the same USB host, able to communicate directly with one another?

A possible topology would be two smartphones connected to a USB hub which in turn is connected to a desktop computer acting as the USB host.

```
                                     ---  Smartphone A
USB host (Desktop)  ---  USB hub  ---|
                                     ---  Smartphone B
```

Comment: Not directly, without the host's explicit help in relaying the messages.

Comment: Side note: if no one explains why the question receives negative votes how am I supposed to know what is wrong with it to improve it and avoid the same mistake in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, USB functions on a kind of master-slave bus topology, where the Host always acts as a master and initiates any transaction happening on the USB bus.
One device connected to the host may not be even able to see the other device, since it's only Host which will have the information about the devices connected to it. The devices will simply provide the function it is meant for.